# ASP.NET - using explicit end tags or not?

Tags: asp.net

Is there any difference between

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server"   .... />
```

and

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" .... ></asp:TextBox>
```

Are there any gotchas using one over the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an exception to @Andrew's rule:
I've been using GridView in an ASP.Net form and binding a recordset to it dynamically for debug purposes (I didn't specify anything for it but an ID).
When you drag the GridView to your form, it creates an `<asp:GridView></asp:GridView>` code. I found out that if I drop the closing tag and close the opener with />, the GridView does not get displayed.

On the same note, check [my question from last week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162420/document-getelementbyid-fails-for-single-tag-div), where people correctly commented that in HTML/XHTML, some tags (like DIV) must have a closing tag.

Comment: As Andres mentioned, if your tag will contain other elements (I can imagine GridView will have child elements), then you have to explicitly close the tag.

Answer (score 4):

No, I prefer the first because it is cleaner and the closing tag serves no purpose.  The only time you need a closing tag rather than using a self-closing element is when you need to out other elements inside the element itself.

Otherwise I always use a self-closing tag for cleanliness and simplicity's sake.

Answer (score 0):

The only tag I've ever seen this make a difference on is a non-ASP.Net related tag, which is `<iframe>`.

I like doing the `/>` instead of a full end tag.  It just seems cleaner.